# Фильтрация textbox

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 - входные данные 2 - выход

Суть программы в том чтобы убрать из textbox все повторы, но по какой-то причине  у меня повторяется первый  убранный элемент
Код: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/82420aad4fd453ebabd6

Прошу не бить тапком, так как программирую на C# первый раз.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так изначальная строка по всей видимости имеет вид

```
"Андрей Соловьев 10,\nАндрей Соловьев 10,\nАндрей Соловьев 10..."
```

и при попытке ее разбить

```
.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
```

получаем что

```
"Андрей Соловьев 10" != "\nАндрей Соловьев 10"
```